# Can I set up stable fully qualified domain names for services in my stack?

Tags: docker, erlang, docker-swarm

I'm trying to get Erlang and Docker Swarm to play together, and I'm having a hard time. The main issue appears to be that Erlang requires my nodes to have fully qualified domain names, or at least something that looks like it (hostnames without periods tend to cause errors).

Previously, I did use a docker overlay network, but not stack/services, and I would run containers manually named "xxx.yyy". Docker would resolve "xxx.yyy", also if nodes were on different hosts, and Erlang was happy. Now, I would like to switch to using docker stack, but in this case Docker no longer resolves by container name but by service name. There is just one issue: periods are illegal in service names, but if I try to name my Erlang nodes as 'nodename@hostname' (without periods) this causes problems on the Erlang side.

I noticed that I can set the "hostname:" property for a service, and there I can include periods, but this name only resolves inside the container itself, it is not recognized over the network.

Is there some way I can set a custom address for a Docker service, which can contain periods, which will resolve properly on nodes of other services, and which remains stable as the service replaces its containers?

NB: I have tried using Erlang's "-sname", but this seems to use the container id as hostname, which still needs to be included when connecting to other nodes over the network, and this is not stable as the service updates/restarts.

NB2: I also found info [here](https://runnable.com/docker/docker-compose-networking) that it might be possible to use the "links:" property, but it looks like that doesn't work on swarm (perhaps only on compose?).

Comment: It looks like inside the swarm things can work if I use -sname. What I did before was use "-sname mynode", then it would set the nodename as "mynode@containerid". If I use "-sname mynode@servicename" instead, that accomplishes most of what I want to do. The only remaining problem is that "-sname" and "-name" nodes can't communicate with each other, so I can't connect my new nodes to my old ones, which can probably be solved by taking the system down and transforming a backup. Still if I could use "-name" with Docker Swarm (i.e. get names with periods resolved) that would be great.

Comment: Interestingly using "mynode@servicename" can be an argument both for -name and -sname. If another -name node tries to connect to it, that gives an error, but somehow if "mynode@servicename" initiates the connection they can actually end up communicating. That will allow me to transfer all the necessary (mnesia) data from my old nodes to new ones, and to switch to -sname after to prevent issues. So it seems for practical purposes my issue is solved, but I'll leave this question here because I think it's still relevant info that's quite hard to find.